# Como colocar 2 botões um ao lado do outro na mesma coluna de uma tabela no html?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

Os 2 botões na ultima coluna da tabela ficam um abaixo do outro. Como faço para por eles lado a lado?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <title>Budget</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/estilo.css">
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../img/favicon.png" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <div class="container">
    <h2>Itens cadastrados</h2>
    <table class="table table-sm">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th>Categoria</th>
                <th>Rubrica</th>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Descrição</th>
                <th>Valor</th>
                <th>Quantidade</th>
                <th>Nota fiscal</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tbody>
                <c:forEach items="${itens}" var="item">
                    <tr>
                        <td> --- </td>
                        <td> --- </td>
                        <td> ${item.nome}</td>
                        <td> ${item.descricao}</td>
                        <td> ${item.getValor_uniforme()}</td>
                        <td> ${item.quantidade}</td>
                        <td>
                            <div>
                                <form action="cadastrarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
                                    <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/adicionar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
                                </form> 
                                <form action="visualizarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
                                    <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
                                    <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/visualizar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
                                </form>
                            </div> 
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </c:forEach>
            </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Essa `<div>` onde estão os botões, é necessária mesmo ou vc só colocou pra testar?

Comment: Só para testar. Porém mesmo sem essa div, o problema persiste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a classe `.btn-group` (**[veja documentação](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/button-group/)**):

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="btn-group">
  <form action="cadastrarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
      <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/adicionar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
  </form> 
  <form action="visualizarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
      <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/visualizar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

**Sem a classe:**

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div>
  <form action="cadastrarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
      <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/adicionar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
  </form> 
  <form action="visualizarNotaFiscal" method="GET">
      <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="${item.id }">
      <button class="btn btn-link"> <img src="../img/visualizar.png" alt="Logo" style="width:100%;"> </button>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, isso resolveu.